# Passing Objective-C method to c++ method

Tags: c++, objective-c

I created void type method in Objective-C to pass it to C++ method shown below:

C++ method to which Objectiv-C method will be passed:

```
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, windowResize);
```

Here is Objective-C method:

```
- (void) windowResize:(GLFWwindow *)window :(int)width :(int)height {glViewport(0, 0, width, height);}
```

I know it can be solved by adding C++ file to the project and linking it to .m file with C++ method, but i would like to implement it in Cocoa syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjC methods can be passed arround as *selector*s like

```
SEL method = @selector(windowResize:width:height:);
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(m_Window, method);
```

Then applied inside glfwSetWindowSizeCallback. Alternately you could wrap the ObjC call in a c function and pass the function pointer.

A more complete example might be:

```
void func(NSApplication * target, SEL method) {
    if ([target respondsToSelector: method] ) {
       [target performSelector:method];
    }
}
```

elsewhere:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    SEL method = @selector(unhideAllApplications:);
    func([NSApplication sharedApplication] , method);
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to use SEL in my code but compiler is coming up with "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant", any clues?

Comment: No I don't know what that would be coming from.